# SQL Server stored procedure for an insert after update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to design a friend's list, similar to other social media sites. I have created 3 tables for this.

- First table contains a list of all the users
- Second table contains the friend's requests
- Third table holds the status codes of the friend request

Designing the database, if user1 sends a request to user143, their status becomes 0 (pending). Once user143 accepts, the status gets updated to 1 (accepted) and user1 becomes friends with user 143.

After the status update, I want to write a stored procedure to automatically insert another row into the friends' request table for user143 to become friends with user1 with a status of 1.

I have a stored procedure to update the status to 1 but not sure how to go about writing the conditional insert (I also have another separate stored procedure for insert that can possibly be used after the IF condition).

Added sample code below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE person_connections_update
    @PersonId INT,
    @FriendId INT,
    @Status INT
AS
    /*
    DECLARE @_personId INT = 1,
            @_friendId INT = 143,
            @_status INT = 1

    EXEC person_connections_update
            @_personId, @_friendId, @_status
    */
BEGIN
    UPDATE person_connections
    SET PersonId = @PersonId,
        FriendId = @FriendId,
        Status = @Status
    WHERE
        PersonId = @PersonId 
        AND FriendId = @FriendId

    -- I'm stuck here
    IF @Status = 1
        INSERT INTO ...
            ...
END
```

**Users** table:

```
+--------+-----------+
| UserId | FirstName |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | Joe       |
|    143 | Bob       |
+--------+-----------+
```

**Status** table:

```
+----+----------+
| Id |  Status  |
+----+----------+
|  0 | Pending  |
|  1 | Accepted |
|  2 | Declined |
+----+----------+
```

**Friends Request** table:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| PersonId | FriendId  |                       Status                       |
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|        1 |       143 | 0 - updates to 1 after user143 acccepts            |
|      143 |         1 | 1 - want to add this row after status updates to 1 |
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to handle this logic instead of firing procedures in sequence... it's what it does, or is designed for. I say this based off your comment *After the status update, I want to write a stored proc to automatically insert another row into the friends' request table for user143 to become friends with user1 with a status of 1*

Comment: You mention the basic architecture of the tables involved. Please post code that creates and loads a schema. It is easy to do and will allow us to visualize your desired outcome with your actual data. More insights here: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Use this tool to generate [ASCII tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps get you more answers!

Comment: @JonJaussi - sorry, added tables into the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a `IF` block in SQL server whithin which a SQL instruction can be executed is as follows :

```
IF (@Status = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ...
    END
END
```